# Kedro - how to set max_workers when running pipelines with ParallelRunner?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, kedro

I'm using Kedro version 0.18.7 and python 3.9 in WSL2.

I'd like to run nodes of my pipeline in parallel by running the command `kedro run --pipeline <pipeline_name> --runner ParallelRunner`. According to the documentation [ParallelRunner](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/kedro.runner.ParallelRunner.html), it should be possible to define the maximum number of CPU cores to use (using `max_workers`), but I am struggling to find out how to use this argument. Apparently I cannot just add it to the command like `--runner ParallelRunner --max_workers 4`.

Does somebody know how to set max_workers for ParallelRunner?

Previous discussions on max_workers are from older versions of Kedro (for example [github issue](https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/issues/809)). I guess I need to create a file somewhere in the project directory and write relevant code, something like `runner=ParallelRunner(max_workers=4)` (cli.py? run.py? settings.py?), but other than that I am lost.

Any tips or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that can work is by creating a kedro session to run your pipeline.

ref: https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/kedro.framework.session.session.KedroSession.html#kedro-framework-session-session-kedrosession

```py
from kedro.framework.session import KedroSession
from kedro.framework.startup import bootstrap_project
from kedro.runner import ParallelRunner
from pathlib import Path

bootstrap_project(Path("<project_root>"))
with KedroSession.create() as session:
    session.run(pipeline_name=<pipeline-name>, runner=ParallelRunner(max_workers=4))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution worked for me with just a minor modification: 

```session.run(pipeline_name=<pipeline-name>, runner=ParallelRunner(max_workers=4))```